# Detailed error on fopen

Tags: php, error-handling, fopen

I'm using fopen to read from a file

```
$fh = fopen($path, 'r') or die('Could not open file');
```

Now I contantly get error Could not open file. I checked the file path and even changed the permissions of the file to 777. Is there a way I can get a detailed error report as why the file can't be opened similar to mysql_error()?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Turn on error reporting, or, in a production environment (from PHP 5.2.0 onwards) you should also be able to use [`error_get_last()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php).

Answer (score 15):

For php versions prior to 5.2 (lacking error_get_last()) you can use [track_errors](http://de.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.track-errors).

```
ini_set('track_errors', 1);
$fh = fopen('lalala', 'r');
if ( !$fh ) {
  echo 'fopen failed. reason: ', $php_errormsg;
}
```

see also: http://de.php.net/reserved.variables.phperrormsg

Answer (score 9):

Yes.
PHP has detailed error message for you.
You just have to turn it on.

To dislay it on the screen add these 2 lines at the top of the script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or if you want it to be logged instead,

```
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also note that using die() is very bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

```
$fh = fopen($path, 'r') or  die (error_get_last());
```